# Unknown source of android permission PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALL

Tags: android, android-permissions

I recently got an email from google suggesting that one of my apps is using the permission PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS.

I looked through my android manifest file for PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, and I also searched the string PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS globally. I still cannot seem to find this permission string.

I do not introduce any mutation of any files in my build process - what should I do next to figure out where my PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS is being specified?

In my manifest,

I only have those specified:

```
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

As suggested by @android_muncher, I used the app manifest viewer to extract the AndroidManifest of my app, and I copy/paste what the extractor is seeing here (with app name changed slightly, and I removed all  tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:versionCode="277"
        android:versionName="2.7.7"
        package="com.myApp.android.partner"
        platformBuildVersionCode="26"
        platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">
        <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="18"
                android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
        <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
        <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <permission
                android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
        <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
                android:required="true"/>
        <library
                android:name="@2131297389"/>
        <uses-permission
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
        <application
                android:theme="@2131558465"
                android:label="@2131296395"
                android:icon="@2130903040"
                android:name="com.myApp.android.model.application.myAppPartnerApplication"
                android:debuggable="true"
                testOnly="true"
                allowBackup="true"
                largeHeap="true"
                supportsRtl="true">
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.receiver.SchedulerReceiver"/>
                <receiver
                        android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.service.local.scheduler.SchedulerService"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <service
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.integration.gcm.myAppPartnerGcmListenerService"
                        android:exported="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </service>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.event.system.connection.NetworkStateChangeReceiver">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.event.system.phone.PhoneBroadcastReceiver">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                                <category
                                        android:name="com.myApp.android"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.integration.gcm.InstanceIDListenerService"
                        android:exported="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </service>
                <service
                        android:name="com.myApp.android.model.integration.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <service
                        android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetUploadService"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <meta-data
                        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
                        android:value="26.1.0"/>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
                        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <service
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
                        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="false"/>
                <receiver
                        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
                        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                                <category
                                        android:name="com.myApp.android.partner"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter
                                android:priority="-500">
                                <action
                                        android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </service>
                <provider
                        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
                        android:exported="false"
                        android:authorities="com.myApp.android.partner.firebaseinitprovider"
                        android:initOrder="100"/>
                <provider
                        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                        android:exported="false"
                        android:authorities="com.myApp.android.partner.multipicker.fileprovider"
                        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                        <meta-data
                                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                                android:resource="@2131165184"/>
                </provider>
                <meta-data
                        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
                        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look through your final manifest file after the application is built. The manifest merger will use the AndroidManifest file from various libraries that you are using in your project. I think some library is using this permission.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: Where can I see the final manifest file? Is that in the apk? In my IDE, i can see a merged Manifest when I open up my androidmanifest.xml, i don't see any errors, and I don't see this process_outgoing_calls either

Comment: Please, read through the link and you will get your answers. Open the manifest file in android studio and click on Merged Manifest at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. I checked the 'Merged Manifest' and I don't see that permission either.

Comment: That seems very strange. I would open the application on a device and use this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en_US to take screenshots of all the permissions that your application uses. Send it to google and ask why your application is being flagged.

Comment: Hey.. Can I send you my android manifest for you to take a look? I am really confused. And google is not helping either =/

Comment: I used your tool, and attached the output in the question section. I am really confused. Not seeing the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALL anywhere